# Powershell Convert html file to pdf using itext.html2pdf

Tags: powershell-4.0, itext7

How to convert html to pdf file in Powershell using itext.html2pdf?

I just want to take my input.html file and get an output.pdf file

I am using iText 7 pdfHTML vewrsion 2.1.3

Here is a C# code in the itext website, but how to convert it to Powershell?.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 using (FileStream htmlSource = File.Open("input.html", FileMode.Open))
 using (FileStream pdfDest = File.Open("output.pdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
 {
   ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
   HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlSource, pdfDest, converterProperties);
 }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not just compiling the code and building an executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to unpack binaries from the following dependencies for .NET environment into the working directory:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle/1.8.1
https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7.pdfhtml/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging/
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Common.Logging.Core/

Then, use the following PowerShell code:

```
Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll"
Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\Common.Logging.Core.dll"
Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\Common.Logging.dll"
Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\itext.io.dll"
Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\itext.kernel.dll"
Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\itext.forms.dll"
Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\itext.layout.dll"
Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\itext.styledxmlparser.dll"
Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\itext.svg.dll"
Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\itext.html2pdf.dll"


$source = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new("D:\temp\input.html")
$dest = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new("D:\temp\output.pdf")
[iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter]::ConvertToPdf($source, $dest)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great, the only thing is that I had to remove this line: Add-Type -Path "D:\temp\itext.kernel.dll", anyway it worked fine. to install the dependencies I did this: 1.- Download nuget.exe from https://www.nuget.org/downloads and save it to C:\Temp folder.
2.- open a command line cmd on D:\Temp folder.
3.- Run next commands:
3.1- nuget install itext7
3.2- nuget install itext7.pdfhtml
3.3- nuget install BouncyCastle -Version 1.8.1

Comment: Hello, Just one more thing. how can I avoid page breaks in my final pdf file?

Comment: @CarlosKassab hi, you are probably looking for a page with very large height? Could you ask another question with specific details on what you want to achieve and what you have now?

Comment: I have a very large plain text file. I converted it to a large html file with company logo and formatting. Now I want to convert this large html file to pdf without page breaks. I see I can convert to pdf but, how to avoid page breaks to have a large pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks and just adding that there is PowerShell module to make it easier to load iText7 without manually adding the dll's.

itext7module : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/IText7Module/1.0.34

```
#load iText7 dll's
initialiseIText7

#Convert file from html to pdf like above
$source = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new("C:\Path\input.html")
$dest = [System.IO.FileInfo]::new("C:\Path\output.pdf")
[iText.Html2Pdf.HtmlConverter]::ConvertToPdf($source, $dest)
```

(I can't comment yet so I had to post this as an answer)

Comment: You can add the PS Gallery as trusted:

`Set-PSRepository -Name PSGallery -InstallationPolicy Trusted`

As for the path, of course change it to point to your html file you want to convert.